# NodeJs backend with Sequelize as my ORM not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I currently have a NodeJS backend and sequelize as my ORM and postgress as my database. I will post below my file structure and can anyone tell me if what im doing is correct or not please. Would really appreciate it.

> config>database.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { Sequelize, QueryTypes } = require("sequelize");

// Configuration for your default database connection (e.g., postgres)
const defaultConnection = new Sequelize('postgres', process.env.PGUSER, process.env.PGPASSWORD, {
  host: process.env.PGHOST,
  dialect: 'postgres',
});

const dbName = process.env.PGDATABASE;

const checkAndCreateDatabase = async () => {
  try {
    // Check if the target database exists
    const dbExists = await defaultConnection.query(
      "SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = '" + dbName + "'",
      { type: QueryTypes.SELECT }
    );

    if (dbExists.length === 0) {
      // If not, create the target database
      await defaultConnection.query('CREATE DATABASE "' + dbName + '"', { type: QueryTypes.RAW });
      console.log(`Database ${dbName} created.`);
    }

    // Close the default connection
    await defaultConnection.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in database creation/check:', error);
    throw error; // Rethrow the error to handle it in calling code
  }
};

// Function to initialize and return the Sequelize connection
const initializeDatabase = async () => {
  await checkAndCreateDatabase();

  // Initialize Sequelize with the target database
  return new Sequelize(
    dbName,
    process.env.PGUSER,
    process.env.PGPASSWORD,
    {
      host: process.env.PGHOST,
      dialect: 'postgres',
      define: {
        // Disable automatic table synchronization
        sync: {
          alter: false
        }
      }
    }
  );
};

module.exports = initializeDatabase;
```

> models>index.js

```
// Remove the Sequelize initialization part since it's done in database.js

const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const db = {};
const defineAssociations = require('./associations');

module.exports = (sequelize) => {
  // Error was due to associations.js it is not a model and there for try below to treat it as a model !!!!!!!!!
  fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter(file => {
      // console.log(file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === ".js" && file !== "associations.js")
      return (
        file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === ".js" && file !== "associations.js"
      );
    })
    .forEach(file => {
      const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, sequelize.DataTypes);
      db[model.name] = model;
    });

  Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
    if (db[modelName].associate) {
      db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
  });

  console.log("Defining associations for models:", Object.keys(db));
  
  defineAssociations(db);

  db.sequelize = sequelize;
  db.Sequelize = sequelize.constructor;

  return db;
};
```

> models>associations.js

```
// models/associations.js
const defineAssociations = (models) => {
  
    // Add associations here
    models.User.hasOne(models.Role, { foreignKey: 'roleId', sourceKey: 'id' });
    models.Role.belongsToMany(models.User, { through: 'user_client_role', foreignKey: 'roleId', otherKey: 'userId' });

    models.User.belongsToMany(models.Client, {
      through: 'user_client_role', // Use the existing table
      foreignKey: 'userId', // Specify foreign key in user_client_role
      otherKey: 'clientId', // Specify other key in user_client_role
    });

    models.Client.belongsToMany(models.User, {
      through: 'user_client_role', // Use the existing table
      foreignKey: 'clientId', // Specify foreign key in user_client_role
      otherKey: 'userId', // Specify other key in user_client_role
    });

  };
  
module.exports = defineAssociations;
```

> models>user.js

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    first_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    last_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true, // Ensures email uniqueness
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    verified: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false, // Assumes users are not verified by default
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW, // Automatically sets created_at on object creation
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW, // Automatically sets updated_at on object update
    },
    deletedAt: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true, // Allows null for future soft deletion implementation
    },
  }, {
    // Add timestamps (createdAt and updatedAt) automatically
    timestamps: true,
  });

  // Define custom associations or methods for the User model here

  return User;
};
```

> routes>user.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
require("dotenv").config();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const models = require("../models");

router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { email, password,firstName,lastName } = req.body;
  
      console.log(req.body)
      // Validate input (Consider more comprehensive validation in production)
      if (!email || !password) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Email and password are required.' });
      }
  
      // Check if user already exists
      const existingUser = await models.User.findOne({ where: { email } });
      if (existingUser) {
        return res.status(409).json({ message: 'User already exists.' });
      }
  
      // Hash password
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10); // 10 is the salt rounds
  
      // Create user
      const user = await models.User.create({
        email,
        password: hashedPassword,
        verified:false,
        first_name:firstName,
        last_name:lastName
      });

        res.status(201).json({
        message: 'User created successfully.',
        userId: user.id,
        });

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
    }
  });


module.exports = router;
```

> app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const compression = require("compression");
const config = require("config");
const {createServer} = require("http");
const {Server} = require("socket.io")
const cors = require('cors');
const cron = require('node-cron');
const dailyNotification = require("./cronJobs/dailyNotification");
const initializeDatabase = require('./config/database'); // Import the database initialization module
const passport = require('./config/passport'); // Adjust the path as necessary
const setupModelsAndAssociations = require('./models'); // This might need to be adjusted based on your file structure
  const user = require("./routes/user"); 
  const token = require("./routes/token"); 
  const me = require("./routes/me"); 

const app = express();
app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 500000}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(helmet({
  frameguard: false
}));
app.use(compression());
app.use(cors())
app.use(passport.initialize());

async function startApp(){
  try{

  // Initialize database and Sequelize instance
  const sequelize = await initializeDatabase();

  // Setup models and associations
  const models = setupModelsAndAssociations(sequelize);
    
    app.use("/api/token/",token(models));
    app.use("/api/user/",user(models));
    app.use("/api/me/",me(models));

    const httpServer =createServer(app);
    
    const port = process.env.PORT || config.get("port");
    
    httpServer.listen(port, function() {
      console.log(`Server started on port ${port}...`);
    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to start application:', error);
}
}

startApp().catch(console.error);
```

this is the error im currently getting:

**Failed to start application: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')
at /Users/karimdakroury/Desktop/Coding/Swhipe2.0/swhipe2-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:646:15
at next (/Users/karimdakroury/Desktop/Coding/Swhipe2.0/swhipe2-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:216:14)
at Function.handle (/Users/karimdakroury/Desktop/Coding/Swhipe2.0/swhipe2-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:175:3)
at router (/Users/karimdakroury/Desktop/Coding/Swhipe2.0/swhipe2-backend/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
at startApp (/Users/karimdakroury/Desktop/Coding/Swhipe2.0/swhipe2-backend/index.js:253:27)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)**